# yesod devel does not refresh site on windows

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, yesod

I am on windows xp.

I run `yesod devel` command during development and expect it to pick up any changes I make, and it does restart when I save a file.

But nevertheless my changes are not reflected in what is shown in the browser (when I refresh the page, for example, after editing the corresponding hamlet template).

Compiling the executable with `cabal install` and running it from the installation directory does show my changes.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

this is happening because yesod cannot "touch":`System.PosixCompat.Files.setFileTimes: not supported: illegal operation`.

Comment: What platform are you on? OS? GHC version? Yesod version? Can you reproduce this with a freshly scaffolded site?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Yesod 0.9.1, GHC 7.0.2, Ubuntu 11.04. I scaffolded a new site, started `yesod devel`, verified the site was running in Chrome, and made a change in `hamlet/homepage.hamlet`. The site automatically rebuilt, and when I hit refresh in Chrome the change was there as expected.

Comment: I am on windows XP. GHC 7.0.3, and I do not know how to view the yesod version. Yes, this is a freshly created application. Perhaps I do not have a clear understanding of what is exactly needed to run a site in development mode. Do i need to install my application package? or would yesod devel suffice? if I have installed the application package in the past, would I need to remove it? I tried to "ghc-pkg unregister" the package, and removing the folder that cabal created for it in AppData/Roaming/cabal, but it did not help.

Comment: I have found the cause, please see the updated question.

Comment: Interesting. You should post that as an answer, and file a bug report on [the Yesod issue tracker](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening because yesod cannot "touch":`System.PosixCompat.Files.setFileTimes: not supported: illegal operation`.

I have opened a bug on that: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues/119